# Study the convergence of a parametrical sum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Determine for which $\alpha >0$ we have absolute convergence or just normal convergence of this sum: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan n$$

**My attempt:** Let's study at first the absolute convergence of this sum: if we denote by $b_n=(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan n$ we have that this is a positive succession so

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan n|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan n$$

Now we have:

$$(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan n = (e^{\frac{1}{n}\log n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan(n) \sim \frac{\log^{\alpha}n}{n^{\alpha}}\arctan n$$

and, by using Cauchy Condensation Test with $c=e$ we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{\alpha}n}{n^{\alpha}}\arctan n < \infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{\alpha}}{e^{n(\alpha-1)}}\arctan n < \infty$$

which is true iff $\alpha > 1$. 
For the standard convergence, using Leibnitz Criterion and reconducting us to this case we can see that the convergence is $\forall \alpha > 0$.

Am I missing something or is it a good proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that Cauchy Condensation test applies for $c\neq 2$? To apply alternating series test we should prove that $\frac{\log^{\alpha}n}{n^{\alpha}}\arctan n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that

$$\arctan n=\frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1n$$

then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan n=\frac{\pi}2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan \frac1n$$

and we have that

$$\sqrt[n]{n}-1=\frac{\log n}n+o\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$$

then

$$(\sqrt[n]{n}-1) ^{\alpha} =\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha}}\left(1+o\left(1\right)\right)^{\alpha}=\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha}}+o\left(\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha}}\right)$$

and thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^no\left(\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha}}\right)$$

converge by alternating series test for any $\alpha>0$ and since

$$\left|(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan \frac1n\right|=\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha+1}}+o\left(\frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha+1}}\right)$$

the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^{\alpha}\arctan \frac1n$$

converges absolutely by limit comaprison test with

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log^{\alpha} n}{n^{\alpha/2+1}}$$

Comment: But you didn't comment my proof, could you?

Comment: For $\alpha>0$ it seems that $|a_n|\to \infty$ if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I think it's false :c

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci Yes of course! I've tried to update with a solution based on your idea but also taking into account the remainder term and dividing the series in order to eliminate the $\arctan n$ term.

Comment: Oh, damn, so the series always converges. I missed a case, bad thing :c Thanks for your answer and the discussion! +1

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci You are welcome! Yes it always converges for $\alpha >0$, maybe there are more direct way to see that, I don't like so much my solution!

Comment: I actually find your solution (which is really similar to mine) not so "beautiful" but surely complete (in your case expecially, formalizing remainders and being precise) and scholastic!

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci Thanks for your appreciation!